# Does Time Machine save TextEdit drafts?

Tags: time-machine, textedit, autosave

Imagine you have **Time Machine** running with Yosemite.

You open **TextEdit**, create a new text document in which you actually write stuff.
You can turn off your computer, restart it, the document will still be there.
But you never saved it once, never. It's just a draft that gets saved as a draft (where?) - when you log out.

Then if you close the window, and lose this document, I assume there's a copy of it somewhere since every time you turned your computer off and on again, the document was there!

But... where would you now look for it in Time Machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time Machine does back them up.

They are kept in
`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Autosave Information/`
File named Unsaved TextEdit Document

so, for Time Machine, it would be
`/Volumes/[TMvolume]/Backups.backupdb/[computer]/Latest/[drive name]/Users/[user]/Library/Autosave Information`
or use the first path & Enter Time Machine, which would probably be simpler.

Comment: The folder "Autosave Information" doesn't have a file called "Unsaved TextEdit Document", neither anywhere through the whole HD or the TM drive linked to it

Comment: Mine does - though not in Latest. I had to find it through 'Enter Time Machine' & go back in time. I haven't tested on a current document, but presumably Time Machine would need chance to pick it up.